# Use JQuery to Select a Select with a Given Select Value

Tags: jquery, selector

I have inherited an MVC forms that emit selects dynamically identified and named by a prefix, a guid, and a suffix. For example,

```
<select id="N9_ID_f0d7ca03-0221-41b7-a457-3494b9e483e3__N9QualifierID" name="N9[ID_f0d7ca03-0221-41b7-a457-3494b9e483e3].N9QualifierID">
    <option value="58">Automated Export System (AES) Internal Transaction Number (ITN)</option>
    <option value="60">Automated Export System Export Information Code Exemption Number (Note 1)</option>
    <option value="59">Automated Export System Option 4 Employee Identification Number</option>
    <option value="8">Bill of Lading</option>
<select>
```

There will be several selects with the same prefix and suffix.  The prefix and suffix effectively partitions the selects into a class and guid ties the dynamically generated selects to other dynamically generated controls such as textboxes.  I need to find the the select that has a given value so I may extract the guid and do stuff with other inputs that have that guid.

My Question:

Using JQuery, how do I select the select(s) that have a given selected value?  For example, I know at least one of the selects will have a selected value of 59, but I don't know which one.

Answer (score 2):

This will return all selects with an option that has 59 as its value.

```
var selects = $('option[value="59"]').parent();
```

If you want the ones that have the 59 as their currently selected value then

```
var selects = $('option[value="59"]:selected').parent();
```

---

Then, once you have the selects, you can use the `.each()` to do what you want with them

```
selects.each(function(){
  // extract guid and do whatever..
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need the property, not the attribute (which doesn't change), so using a filter should work

```
$('select').filter(function() {
    return this.value === '59';
}).prop('id');
```